# Python logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler breaks when inside loop

Tags: python, django, logging

I am using `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` for my logging needs in Django with a maximum byte size of 1KB.

However if I do this:

```
for i in range(1,500):
    logger.debug('Hello World')
```

Then the app crashes and I get a nice Windows Error 32 saying that the log file can't be accessed because it's already in use by another process

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
WindowsError: [Error 32] ─ The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Which sort of makes sense since at the split second that the max size is reached the app is still inside the for loop and keeps printing.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852555/rotatingfilehandler-text-file-busy-in-windows

Comment: @DRC Yeap. That did the trick!